# String to number conversion using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

This is my html code but the problem is that if I add two strings it always gives the 50 as the addition.

```
 function add()
  {
   var fname=document.getElementById("fname");
   var lname = document.getElementById("lname");

   var fstring = fname.toString();
   var lstring = lname.toString();

    var fl = fstring.length;
    var ll = lstring.length;  

   var f1 = parseInt(fl,10);
   var l1 = parseInt(ll,10);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = f1 + l1;
   }
</script>
```

Comment: I'm a little confused at the question? Calling `.length` on a string will return how many characters it contains, so for example `"bacon".length` would result in 5. Edit: just figured out the issue - see may answer below.

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: What are you entering into fname and lname to get "50"?

Answer (score 2):

Because you are NOT reading the value of the input

```
   var fname=document.getElementById("fname");
   var lname = document.getElementById("lname");

   var fstring = fname.toString();  //<-- turning object to string
   var lstring = lname.toString();  //<-- turning object to string
```

needs to be

```
   var fname=document.getElementById("fname");
   var lname = document.getElementById("lname");

   var fstring = fname.value;  
   var lstring = lname.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are getting the Element itself, rather than the content of the given element. For example if `fname` was an input, you'd want to call

```
var fname=document.getElementById("fname").value;
```

Current what I'm guessing is happening is that calling `toString()` on the element itself returns something like `[object HTMLInputElement]`, hence why you always get the same lengths when you do the addition.

If you get the values rather than the elements, your code should then work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
var fstring = fname.toString();
var lstring = lname.toString();
```

This tries to convert the HTMLElement objects to string, while what you probably want is the value stored in those inputs.

```
var fstring = fname.value;
var lstring = lname.value;
```

Also, you don't need to do this:

```
var fl = fstring.length;
var ll = lstring.length;
var f1 = parseInt(fl,10);
var l1 = parseInt(ll,10);
```

The length property is a number already.

If you wanted to get the total length of both names, just do
`total = fstring.length + lstring.length;`
If you wanted to concatenate them, do
`fullname = fstring + " " + lstring;`

And finally, don't put 1's and small L's in short variable names like that, this can become quite confusing.

Answer (score 0):

**Use This**

```js
function add(){
var fname=document.getElementById("fname");
   var lname = document.getElementById("lname");

   var fstring = fname.value.toString();
   var lstring = lname.value.toString();
   var fullName = fstring +" "+lstring;
   alert(fullName )
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='fname'/>
<input type='text' id='lname'/>
<input type='button' id='btnOk' onclick='add()' value='OK'/>
```

Comment: This is not that i want. I want to convert char to integer such as "hello" to 32 or any other number.